# How to XOR a list of binary string with just a string in python

Tags: python

```
ListOfBinString  = ['00110110101000111010000011000100000010000110001011', '10110111100111111110001111100011100101011010111010', '11101000111010100101111111001010000110100110110110', '11101111010111000101111111001010101001100101111011']

binString = "10000010001110010011101001010000110000110011100000"

#Code sample

string = ""
for i in ListOfBinString:
    string = string + hex(int(i)^ int(binString))
print(string)
```

My goal is to Xor each string in ListOfBinString using binString, then return all the Xored value as a single string.

Comment: This is easy, but I think you ought to try it yourself first as this appears to be a class exercise, and trying it yourself helps you learn.

Comment: I've tried it myself, will include my code right away

Comment: @AndrewAllaire that's my code, but I'm getting an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: The string addition is just going to concatenate to a longer and longer string. It seems what they are asking for is to treat the strings as a lot of bits and do a bitwise xor to end up with a sting of the same length also of 1s and 0s.

Comment: You will need to convert the strings to their integer equivelent in base 2. For example binString can be converted by: binInt = int(binString, 2)

Comment: For each element on the list you can get the base 2 integer equivalent and use ^ or ^= operator to combine it with your binInt value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert from string to int with base 2 and then do the XOR operation

```
string = ""
for i in ListOfBinString:
    string = string + hex(int(i,2)^int(binString,2))
print(string)
```